# Get item from array to dataframe column based on index and column value match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consist of two columns and an array consist of few elements as below

```
df

Index  col1  col2
0      4      1
1      3      2
2      5      3
3      3      1

arr = ["low", "medium", "neutral", "high", "unknown"]
```

I want to match the index of array with `col1` and `col2` values and get the array values in `col1` and `col2` as below :

```
Index     col1            col2
    0      unknown      low
    1      high         medium
    2      unknown      high
    3      high         low
```

How can I do that. Can someone please help to suggest any way.

Comment: You can use `.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this. Here is another two. It's easiest to 'map' from a Dictionary which is easily formed from a List:

```
import pandas as pd

arr = ["low", "medium", "neutral", "high", "unknown"]
mapper = {i+1 :x for i, x in enumerate(arr)}

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [4, 3, 5, 5],
                   'col2': [1, 2, 3, 1]
                    })

df1 = df.replace(mapper)

df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(mapper).fillna('missing')
df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(mapper).fillna('missing')

print(df)
print(df1)
```

which gives:

```
      col1     col2
0     high      low
1  neutral   medium
2  unknown  neutral
3  unknown      low

      col1     col2
0     high      low
1  neutral   medium
2  unknown  neutral
3  unknown      low
```

Note that `.map` replaces unmappable values with NaN but this can be replaced as shown; `.replace` leaves unknown values 'as is'. A dictionary is very flexible since it can be formed to change any value to anything - so the index relationship would not have to be used.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, indexing is 0-based, we will subtract 1 from the dataframe values to match with the array index.

We assume that your dataframe is named `df` and your list is named `arr`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [4, 3, 5, 3],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3, 1]
})

arr = ["low", "medium", "neutral", "high", "unknown"]

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: arr[x - 1])
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: arr[x - 1])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [4, 3, 5, 3],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3, 1]
})

arr = ["low", "medium", "neutral", "high", "unknown"]
d = dict(zip(range(1,6),arr))

df['col1'] = df['col1'].map(d)
df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(d)

print(df)

    col1    col2
0   high    low
1   neutral medium
2   unknown neutral
3   neutral low
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(arr)[df.values-1], columns=df.columns)
```

---

Or simply:

```
df[df.columns] = np.array(arr)[df.values-1]
```

---

Output:

```
      col1     col2
0     high      low
1  neutral   medium
2  unknown  neutral
3  neutral      low
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `applymap()`

```
df[['col1','col2']].applymap(dict(enumerate(arr,1)).get)
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2
0     high      low
1  neutral   medium
2  unknown  neutral
3  neutral      low
```